# Incipit di "All'ombra delle fanciulle in fiore"

Tags: translation, grammatical-analysis

Questo è l'incipit del romanzo di Proust in una traduzione in italiano:

> Mia madre, quando si trattò di avere per la prima volta a pranzo M. de Norpois, siccome si rammaricava che il professor Cottard fosse in viaggio e lei stessa non frequentasse più del tutto Swann perché sia l’uno sia l’altro avrebbero potuto suscitare l’interesse dell’ex ambasciatore, mio padre rispose che un ospite eminente, un illustre scienziato come Cottard non poteva mai sfigurare in un pranzo, ma Swann con il suo esibizionismo, con quella sua maniera di gridare ai quattro venti le relazioni anche più insignificanti, era un volgare sbruffone che il marchese di Norpois, secondo una sua tipica espressione, avrebbe trovato “pestifero”.

Dal punto di vista dell'analisi logica, cos'è "Mia madre"?

Ho controllato il testo in francese e chiesto una domanda analoga [qui](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52583/logical-analysis-of-the-incipit-of-prousts-in-the-shadow-of-young-girls-in-flo).

Secondo me però in italiano non fila la frase.

Comment: È una domanda interessante. Potresti per favore completarla con l'indicazione del traduttore della versione che stai citando?

Comment: Concordo che la traduzione sembra un po' strana. Ad esempio, quest'altra traduzione comincia con "A mia madre [...] mio padre rispose [...]" larecherche.it/public/librolibero/… . In francese 'ma mère'  è il soggetto del gerundio 'ayant exprimé le regret ', letteralmente sarebbe 'avendo mia madre espresso il rammarico […] mio padre rispose ’. –